# Google Sheets Query comparing col value with Percentage

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with values similar to below

| Name. | Score | Location | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 78% | AMER | 12/12/23 |
| John | 42% | EMEA | 12/25/22 |
| Peter | 72% | AMER | 12/25/22 |

I want to use query function to extract the Name, Score, Location, Date WHERE the Score is greater than 70% I tried the query below with the quotations around the >70% in various places but either get an error or not the correct results

`=QUERY('Raw Data'!A3:H,"SELECT A,B, C D WHERE (B >'70%')",1`

I am wanting to use the result to build a chart with slicers to be able to slice by date and location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'70%'` treating as text comparison. Try-

```
=QUERY(A2:D,"SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE (B >.7)",1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to write it as a percentage

```
=QUERY('Raw Data'!A3:H,"SELECT A,B, C, D WHERE B >"&70%,1)
```

[image]